# Is there a good way to infer ranges of numbers from postal codes?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of zipcodes (Of various countries) of this format:

`["100-1001","102-1000","102-1001","102-1002","100-1002","111","112","102-1003","113"]`

I'll need to infer ranges from these numbers in the output format of:

`[[upper1,lower1],[upper2,lower2]]`

For the above example this would be:

`[["100-1001","100-1002"]["102-1000","102-1003"]["111","113"]]`

Is there a better way than to convert everything as flat numbers, removing the delimiters ,inferring their ranges and then re-adding delimiters?

Currently I have this logic for non-hyphenated postal codes -

```
getRanges(zipCodes) {
  zipCodes.sort();
  let length = 1;
  let ranges = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= zipCodes.length; i++) {
    if (i == zipCodes.length || zipCodes[i] - zipCodes[i - 1] != 1) {
      if (length == 1) {
        let upper = lower = zipCodes[i - length];
        ranges.push({lower, upper});
      }
      else {
        let lower = zipCodes[i - length];
        let upper = zipCodes[i - 1];
        ranges.push({lower, upper});
      }
      length = 1;
    }
    else {
      length++;
    }
  }
  return ranges;
}
```

But I feel the extra overhead of removing and re-adding delimiters could be avoided if there's a better way of parsing the ranges. thanks in advance

Comment: when you describe `[100-1001, 102-1000, 102-1001, 102-1002, 100-1002, 111,112,113]` are you saying that the values are strings, or that it is actually `[100, 101, 102,`...`1001, 102, 103, 104,`...`]` and so on? or is it `[-901, -898,`...`]`?

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch These are strings that are parsed as numbers if the hyphen is removed. So technically they'll be [1001001, 1021000, 1021001, 1021002, 1001002, 111,112,113]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be convert the input to a list of `number,string` pairs, sort/classify based on the numbers and finally extract the strings from the result:

```js
function getRanges(arr) {
    let pairs = arr.map(s => [
        Number(s.replace(/\D+/g, '')),
        s
    ])

    pairs.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])

    let ranges = [], last = null

    for (let p of pairs) {
        if (last && last[1][0] === p[0] - 1)
            last[1] = p
        else
            ranges.push(last = [p, p])
    }

    return ranges.map(r => [r[0][1], r[1][1]])
}

const zipCodes = [
    "100-1000",
    "100-1001",
    "100-1002",
    "100-1003",

    "100-1005",

    "200-1000",
    "200-1001",
    "200-1002",

    "200-1006",

    "111",
    "112",

    "114",
    "115",
    "116",
]

console.log(getRanges(zipCodes))
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The sort function can work with strings too. So without removing the `-` this will order the array of zip-codes and group them by pairs:

```js
function getRanges(zipCodes) {
  zipCodes.sort();
  let ranges = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= zipCodes.length - 1; i += 2) {
    if (zipCodes[i + 1]) {
      let lower = zipCodes[i];
      let upper = zipCodes[i + 1];
      ranges.push({lower, upper});
    } else {
      let upper = lower = zipCodes[i];
      ranges.push({lower, upper});
    }

  }
  return ranges;
}
const zipCodes = ["100-1001", "102-1000", "102-1001", "102-1002", "100-1002", "111", "112", "113"];
const result = getRanges(zipCodes);
console.log(result);
```

**Update:**
This code doesn't solve the OP requirements, but several people upvoted it, since it sorts & groups the zip-codes. (I think several people, including me, misunderstood how the grouping was supposed to take place).

The correct way is [georg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69321862/9801177) and the only improvement I would think of, is sorting before doing the actual `map` so it returns the same order as the original request. Otherwise I can't think of a better implementation, so I'll leave my original code that got upvoted if anyone finds it useful.

Comment: The sort is fine, but this doesn't generate ranges of like-formatted codes, it just pairs adjacent indexes.

Comment: This generates the output
[{
  lower: "100-1001",
  upper: "100-1002"
}, {
  lower: "102-1000",
  upper: "102-1001"
}, {
  lower: "102-1002",
  upper: "102-1002"
}]

for input:  ["100-1001", "102-1000", "102-1001", "102-1002", "100-1002"];

But ideally it should do 
{
  lower: "102-1000",
  upper: "102-1002"
}

Comment: Why is this getting upvotes? it returns `{ "lower": "102-1002", "upper": "111" },` as a range

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the comments sooner. I updated my answer so it reflects the problem with your request. (I misunderstood how the grouping was supposed to work). Thanks for pointing it out